# AngularJS: Passing dynamic data into directive controller via attribute

Tags: angularjs

I know there are multiple ways pass data into a directive. This question is asking if it is possible to pass data into a directive dynamically using an externally defined controller and no link function. Let's start with something that works:

```
<stars stars-rating="{{someVM.property}}"></stars>
```

where the stars directive is defined as:

```
angular.module('module-stars', [])
.directive('stars', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: false,
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        var stars = parseFloat(attr.starsRating);

        try {
            scope.wholeStars = new Array(Math.floor(stars + .33));
            scope.emptyStars = new Array(Math.floor(5.33 - stars));
            scope.halfStars = 5 - scope.wholeStars.length - scope.emptyStars.length;
        } catch (e) {}
    },
    templateUrl: 'modules/stars/stars.tmpl.html'
};
});
```

This works fine, but this is a very large application and for maintainability, I would prefer to to use the same patterns throughout the app. My basic pattern is as follows:

```
angular.module('module-stars', [])
.directive('stars', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: false,
    templateUrl: 'modules/stars/stars.tmpl.html',
    controller: 'starsCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'stars'
};
});
```

with the controller externally defined:

```
angular.module('module-stars')
.controller('starsCtrl', ['$attrs',
function ($attrs) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.id = 'starsCtrl';
    vm.text = commonService.getText('stars');

    var stars = parseFloat($attrs.starsRating);

    try {
        vm.wholeStars = new Array(Math.floor(stars + .33));
        vm.emptyStars = new Array(Math.floor(5.33 - stars));
        vm.halfStars = 5 - vm.wholeStars.length - vm.emptyStars.length;
    } catch (e) {}

}]);
```

If I use this pattern, then $attrs.starsRating will be the string "{{someVM.property}}" instead of the value of someVM.property. Any suggestions, or is this just the way Angular works here.

Comment: Why not use [isolate scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) and either a two-way `=` or expression `&` binding?

Comment: Isolating scope does work with `scope: {starsRating: '@'}` assuming I inject $scope into the controller. $attrs still seems to register `"{{someVM.property}}"`. Swear I tried that yesterday. Thank you. I should add for others that `=` and `&` errored